# Why does Rabbitmq server fail to log in?

Tags: rabbitmq

I use rabbitmq-server in Ubuntu 18.04.

I install rabbitmq-server through "sudo apt-get install rabbitmq-server"

And i run rabbitmq-server.service through "sudo systemctl start rabbitmq-server.service"

then, i checked "netstat -ntlp", cause port open(5672, 15672).

However, the following error log occurs.

```
=ERROR REPORT==== 24-Jan-2022::13:52:48 ===
Error on AMQP connection <0.5608.0> (127.0.0.1:45718 -> 127.0.0.1:5672, state: starting):
PLAIN login refused: user 'test_rabbit' - invalid credentials
```

What is the reason for this error and is there a solution to it?